# How to create menu item in admin menu Joomla 4 in php+mysql in module, plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla-4.x, linux

[image]

How to create menu item in admin menu Joomla 4 in php? From plugin/module for Joomla4?

Comment: That you for asking your question on JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins and Module don't have their own Admin Menu items. In the back-end via "Menus > Manage" you can **create new Admin Menu items** but only **to Component Views**.

There's an option to create Menu Items of Menu Item Type "System Links > URL" but you cannot use that to trigger your Modules or Plugins.

Comment: In "wordpress cms" I can add item to admin menu in php code of "plugin for wordpress".

Comment: In Joomla you can do it with core Joomla and without plugins: using the admin menu like I described, or even with a template override.